# How do I create a SSIS package that uploads documents to an FTP site? The documents to be uploaded will be determined via a SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

How do I create a SSIS package that uploads documents to an FTP site? The documents to be uploaded will be determined via a SELECT statement, which will return a list of local UNC paths to be uploaded.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you dropped an FTP task in an SSIS package yet?

Comment: Yes, I'm just not sure how to configure it to use the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the same approach as the various For Each samples (i.e. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS).

Run a select statement, load it into a SSIS variable of type OBJECT. Iterate through that object in a For Each Object iterator, inside the iterator, run your FTP command.

I've never used the FTP command before but I have heard that it has very limited support for expressions. If you find you cannot update the required attributes of the FTP component then there are workarounds.

An example workaround is export your file list to a text file, then use a command line FTP client to FTP all the files in the text file.

Comment: Sorry I'm very green with SSIS. Can you be more specific. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some more detail. But first, go through and understand the link I sent. Instead of `select connectionstring from dbo.server`, use the SQL you have to get the list of files. And instead of putting a data flow inside the loop, put an FTP task. Try that and get back to me.